# Cant retrieve the full date range of data request

Tags: missing-data, dateadd

My Code;
FROM UtilisationData d

WHERE

```
d.DateofVisit >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()) - 8, 0)
```

Issue:- I am asking the system to retrieve 8 weeks of data however it is always skipping the final week for example if I pulled today it will pull 8/1/2018 - 28/02/2018 Missing the data for the beginning of March. I have tried multiple different searches including DAY -57 code and including and end range as well. I have also attempted to pull just the March dates but that doesn't work either. I have checked my multiple tables for other codes and the March request is pulling through fine so not sure why this one just doesn't want to pull it through.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the database server-what version of SQL?

Comment: 2008 R2, sorry for the late response, the website wouldn't let me add the comment

Comment: Something seems missing from your example. The datediff function is returning 2018-01-08, so the WHERE clause woud be returning everything after that, up to the present and future. Where does the other date (2018-02-28) come from?

Comment: That's what I can't understand. I even tried adding AND d.DateofVisit < DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()) - 0, 0) In theory my statement should be pulling through all data stored with what I have written but it just won't pull through any data for March at all.

Comment: The where clause that you're giving above will return everything from 1/15/18 to present.  Executing 
"select DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()) - 8, 0)" will whow you that.  There has to be more to your where clause or perhaps a join that's limiting the data.. The fragment you've given does not give an upper bound on the date, it only specifies the earliest date.

Comment: You are right, had a table join which was causing this issue. Have removed it and it now works. Thank you soo much for all you help

Comment: Glad to see you worked it out.